# Cannot debug a F# library project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, f#, nunit, visual-studio-debugging, f#-fake

I'm using VS2015.

Yesterday I installed .net 4.7 and nuget test adapter (don't know if either one of them could be the cause, apparently they are not related to the issue).

I'm having some problems when I build and debug an F# library project

I'm getting frequent errors:

```
"error MSB3027: Could not copy "obj\Debug\...

"error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj...
```

More importantly I'm not able to set a breakpoint in the library code

```
“The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.”
```

when I try to load symbols pdb from the module window, I get:`"A matching symbol file was not found in this folder"`

I've tried to clean, rebuild, attach to process, set native, managed and compat mode debugger... I've set define debug and trace constant and deactivated optimizations. No luck till now.

Comment: Something is holding your DLL files - like maybe another debugger or a running instance of your program. Use process explorer to find who is holding the files and stop it.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the solution structure and I started building the solution from Visual Studio, before running the build script.

> We use Fake and Paket. You have to run build.cmd on Windows

Moreover they reported known issues about debugging and file locking in the above said section.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer:)